# Is there a way to enable the console?

Tags: overwatch

In other games like Source-based games like CS:GO or TF2 or UE3 games like Dirty Bomb and Unreal Tournament I am able to enable the console in order to set binds, or play with commands to test specific features or practice in gameplay.

In Overwatch itself, is there a way to manually enable the console? Is there a console at all? I've tried the tilde key and combing through the options-control menu and haven't found a setting for enable console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In past Blizzard games such as `Diablo 2` and `Diablo 3` you could access some console like commands from the chat window, they weren't cheats and some were game mechanic changing [options](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Game_commands).

According to this [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4lfe9t/list_of_chat_commands/) thread Overwatch seems to follow a similar structure but almost all of it is to do with actual chat and nothing that changes game mechanics.

> I was looking for some list of chat commands, but couldn't find any so
>   I decided to put the list together, hope you find it useful.
>
> ```
> /all or /a or /general - Switch to general chat
> /accept - Accept the current group invite
> /customgame or /cg - Switch to custom game chat
> /decline - Decline the current group invite
> /group or /g or /p - Switch to group chat
> /leave - Leave your group
> /leavechannel - Leave the current channel
> /list - List all players in your channel
> /logout - Log out of the game
> /match or /m - Switch to match chat
> /reply or /r - Reply to last player
> /spectate - Spectate a friend
> /team or /t - Switch to team chat
> ```
>
> Those above have description right in game, for the rest correct me
>   where I'm wrong.
>
> ```
> /invite - Invite player to your group
> /joinchannel or /join - Join a channel
> /kick - Remove player for your group
> /leader - ?
> /promote - ?
> /removefriend - Remove friend from your friendlist
> /whisper or /w or /send or /tell - Send message to a player
> ```

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, there is no console in Overwatch, hence no way to enable it.

Comment: Plain and simple :) The best kind of answer hah

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that no console _at all_ exists? Perhaps saying that no "user-accessible console" exists would be a better way of phrasing this answer.

Comment: @pushasha of course there is a developer console in all blizzard games, but they are left out from production builds.

Comment: @ardaozkal My point exactly. I was getting picky with your phrasing -- specifically, that you have no way of knowing (unless you worked on the game) whether the console was "left out", or just disabled in a way such that users are prevented from accessing it. Not worth discussing any further... I just find answers where things are stated as fact (when they are, in fact, a highly-probable assumption) a bit misleading. I'll try to rein in my impulse to comment on things like that in the future.

Comment: @pushasha I'm not sure about overwatch not having one or just having one which is not accessible, but on D3 I remember reading a post by a dev about that.